# Зависит ли производительность Oracle Database от количества созданных схем (т.е. пользователей)?

Tags: oracle, база-данных, производительность

Например, в одном инстансе есть три схемы на 400MB, 300MB и 200MB. Будет ли оракл занимать меньше ресурсов (и следовательно вырастет производительность), если оставить только первую схему, а остальные удалить?
Спрашиваю потому что где-то давно читал что оракл загружает бд в память и меня интересует что если я работаю только с первой схемой находятся ли в памяти остальные с которыми я не работаю.

Comment: Сомневаюсь что есть влияние на скорость работы. Разве что время чтения файлов падает за счет увеличения времени поиска в FAT. Даже если так, этим можно пренебречь.

наши dba шутят - самая важная оптимизация oracle db, - миграция с windows на linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество пользователей на производительность БД не влияет. По умолчанию в оракле создаётся около полусотни пользователей ([ссылка](http://baks.gaz.ru/oradoc/ora/ora029.htm)).